# Create windows directory with 3 digits

Tags: windows

in windows I can create folders with the following command

```
for /l %i in (1,1,199) do md prefix-%a
```

But that gives me a dir with prefix-1, what I want is 001, 002...010..100 etc

I can't fill the zero's with the prefix, because I would get something like prefix-0010. It has to be 3 digits.

Is that possible within windows?